# In MakeCrud.php line 103: Call to a member function getRepositoryClass() on null

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a crud in `Symfony 4.4` with `bin/console make:crud` command but I'm getting the following error

```
In MakeCrud.php line 103:

  Call to a member function getRepositoryClass() on null
```

this is part of the class I'm trying to use for the crud

```
<?php

namespace Domain\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

    class Segment
    {
        private $id;
    
        private $uidentifier;
    
        private $name;
```

I type the class name with the namespasce oto genterate crud but I get the error, what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you registered this class as an entity?

Comment: I don't know it's not my code, where should I search?I guess It is because I can store on the database with a command app on the same project

Comment: In a typical Symfony/Doctrine application, entities live under App\Entity as opposed to Domain\Entity.  If I had to guess, make:crud expects the entity to be in the App\Entity namespace.  You could test this by creating a simple App\Entity\Segment and see if the command runs.

Answer (score 1):

So I got a little bit curious and confirmed that it is a namespace issue.

I made myself a Domain\Entity\Segment class and then ran

```
bin/console make:crud 'Domain\Entity\Segment'
```

And got the same error message.

The make:crud command expects entities to live under App\Entity.  Does not seem to be any way to convince it to look under Domain\Entity just for entities.

However the Maker Bundle itself allows you to change the name of the App's root namespace:

```
# config/packages/maker.yaml Need to add this file
maker:
  root_namespace: Domain

# Then run
bin/console make:crud Segment
```

And it works.  The problem is that the root namespace is used for generating all the files so, for example, you end up with a Domain\Controller\SegmentController class which is probably not where you want them to be.

I checked the source and there is no easy way to adjust just the entity namespace.  If you plan on using crud quite a bit then you either need to copy your entities to App\Entity or specify the root_namespace and then copy/refactor your generated controllers and forms.  Either way it will be a pain.

I suppose you could also fork the maker bundle and edit the source code directly.  Might actually be worth the effort if you have a bunch of crud to generate.  But that will be left as an exercise.